# Symfony 2.1.2 memcache session kinda SSO

Tags: session, symfony, memcached, symfony-2.1

I'm kinda lost in all the session stuffs in Symfony. I'm gonna explain what I want to achieve and I only want to be pointed out on the right track.

I have PHP session stored in memcache (I don't have choice due to past systems). And in my Symfony site I have to plug it in memcache too, no problem here. But before starting a session I have checks to do to see if my user already has a session in memcache from another site to get informations ... and then set my session id to this one.

I've tried to extend `Session`, but it seems it's not the right place to do so.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement [this solution](http://hipaway.com/blog/symfony2-sessions-in-memcache/) with memcache.
As far as I can see, it works but I can't find any session related data set in my memcache server.
But it seems to be a good starting point for working ;-)
Also interesting is the [documentation of all default values](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session) for the framework configuration (app/config/config.yml) in the sf2 docs.
Maybe that helps :-)

Comment: Hi,
Yes I've seen this but as you said I can"t get any information from my memcache server and I can't get the existing session id to get those informations back. I'm trying to get the point where sf2 create the session to override it ... but this is kinda complicated.
Keep ourselves posted ;)

Comment: I've found a script to shop Memcache-Server infos (http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/). Also I've dumped $this->getRequest()->getSession() where you can clearly see that our configured storage handler is used. But if it's actually called to store the data... dunno. Still debugging ;-)

Comment: Ok, now it's clear: You'll also have to configure your php.ini to use memcache as session handler.

Comment: Yes I've the configuration both in php.ini and in sf2 just to be sure :D
But my main problem is still that I want to get an existing session in memcache to sf2

Comment: Ok, strange thing: I've got the configuration in both, sf2 and php.ini and now its working. But I've got an rather odd environment here. sf2 integrated into typo3 (old version) as an extension ;-)

Comment: Actually I need to override the session id with the session I already have in memcache ... if I have one ... I've tried to extends NativeSessionStorage as I found on Google but it doesn't seem to do the trick anymore :( Still investigating.

Comment: Ohhh nice one ! I'm TYPO3 certified ;)

Comment: I'm using the session from Typo3, since I'm manually initializing the framework and also building the request object via Request::createFromGlobals() with an altered $_SERVER array in the extension. That includes all session/cookie etc. data into my request object.

Comment: That's what i don't like about links. They break. now i have absolutely no Idea what your solution was!